# How to use AjaxResponse.Render() to replace a span's text in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, ajax-request

I am replacing 2 divs using with AjaxResponse.Render() which have 2 associated partial views with them.

But there a span like the following:

```
<span id="total-counts">23 comments</span>
```

I need to replace this value as well. How do I call the with AjaxResponse.Render() to replace this value?

There is no associated view with this span. It might be easy thing but I can't make it work.

I tried these:

Note the second param is the view name.

```
AjaxResponse.Render("#total-counts", "string", comments.Count, UpdateStyle.Replace);
AjaxResponse.Render("#total-counts", "", comments.Count, UpdateStyle.Replace);
```

None of these work. I don't want to create a partial view unless it is the only way.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

On Ajax Success Callback use as

```
 $("#total-counts").html(' ');
 $("#total-counts").html(comments.Count+" Comments");
```

Comment: I don't access to the Count in client side.